# Minimum sum of products for boolean expression

Tags: logic, optimization, boolean-algebra

I am trying to find the minimum sum of products expansion for the following Boolean Algebra expression - 
(A + ~B + C~D + CE + ~D~E)(~B + ~C + ~D + ~E)

and I am unable to arrive at the final answer. The answer given by online calculators is A~C + A~E + ~B + C~D + ~D~E but I don't understand how to get rid of the A~D term after evaluating the brackets.

Any help in breaking this down will be greatly appreciated.